# Is this the best way to check if a variable is defined, not null and equal to "" or anything else

Tags: javascript

I need to set a value if my variable is defined, not null and equal to "" or anything else.

I am using the following:

```
if (typeof abc != 'undefined') {
   if (abc != null) {
      // Here the variable abc must be defined
      // not null
      // equal to "" or anything else such as a longer string or number
   }   
}
```

Can someone tell me if this is best way for me to implement the check that I need.

Comment: So you'd like to check if it's anything not null or undefined?

Comment: @Qantas - Yes that's correct

Comment: why not just `if( abc )` ?

Comment: A var cannot be of type undefined. If the var is not within current scope, you'll get a reference error when using it. An object's property can be of type undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
var abc2 = abc.toString();

if (abc2.length > 0)
```

If length > 0 so, it's setted

Comment: What happens if `abc = 0`?

Comment: This will raise an exception if abc is not defined

Comment: @Jahnux73: unless you're going to be expecting a string, it's not the _best_ thing to be doing, but it's not entirely wrong.  Just a note that this will still throw an exception if `abc` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript validates any of those cases as booleans, so:

```
if ( abc ) {
    ....
}
```

checks all of those cases.